# Actions Builder: delay transition to the next scene (ideally, until the speech has finished)

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to implement some minimal synchronization between the screen and the speech.

I want my action to say something like "Give me a second..." then wait for a few seconds, then say "OK, I am ready. The answer is 42." and display "42" on the screen.

Without synchronization it would not work: even though the voice says "give me a second...", the answer is displayed on the screen immediately.

I split my prompt into two scenes and hoping to find a way to add either a delay before transitioning or, even better, a condition that will become true after the speech has completed.

Are you aware of any way to achieve this?

Or, is there any other way to synchronize between the screen output and the TTS output?

Answer (score 0):

You can split up your response into `first_simple` and `last_simple`.
The text form `last_simple` would be displayed after the speech from the `first_simple` ends. This only works for Phones not for SmartDisplays!

For more details about implementation and system limits have a look at the Docs https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-simple

If you are creating a Game you can also use Interactive Canvas with On to sync display and Voice.https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/web-apps#onttsmark

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @kglass. I am looking for a solution that works across various devices. I was hoping to stay out of Interactive Canvas :)